# Insert post data into MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bottle

I have a row/s of fields being posted in a view with their names numbered per each row, e.g. `01_field1`, `01_field2`, `02_field1`, `02_field2` etc. The user can add and remove rows, so I won't know how many rows are posted. In other words, I want to be able to group the post key and values by their row number.

Here is an example of what is being posted i.e. the value of 'items'

```
[('01_cost', 'value'), ('01_date_end', 'value'), ('01_date_start', 'value'), ('01_hours', 'value'), ('01_resource', 'value'), ('01_task_desc', 'value'), ('02_cost', 'value'), ('02_date_end', 'value'), ('02_date_start', 'value'), ('02_hours', 'value'), ('02_resource', 'value'), ('02_task_desc', 'value'), ('job_description', 'value'), ('job_number', 'value')]
```

I am trying to loop though the sorted post items and insert into MongoDB in the following nested format:

```
{
    "row1": {
                "01_field1": "value", 
                "01_field2": "value"
            },
    "row2": {
                "02_field1": "value", 
                "02_field2": "value"
            },
}
```

I am currently trying to generate a list of dicts for each row, but this doesn't appear to be inserting into mongo as above. Here is the (not working) code I currently have.

```
items = sorted(request.POST.items())

project_data = []
d = {}
etid = '01'

for key, value in items:
    #get the number from each posted field name
    tid = re.findall(r'\d+', key)

    if etid == tid:
        d.update({key:value})
    else:
        project_data.append(d)
    etid = tid

project_id = project.insert(project_data)
```

Comment: project is a collection? do you receive any error? are your connected to the database? does `project.find_all()` returns anything? post the content of `project_data` once it is ready to be inserted.

Comment: project is a Mongo collection. No error, I have had the data inserting into Mongo so connection is fine. My challenge is getting the post values into a format that will insert into Mongo as required. The right combination of dict/lists and pymongo insert handling is what I think i'm looking for.

Comment: the issue I see here is that project_data is a list, and the structure you show as your desired insert format is a dict.

Comment: also, you are appending the same dict several times in the list, so your list is probably only consisting of n times the same dict. can you post an example of input ?

Comment: Good point!! Will go back and take a look at the code. Thanks.

Comment: when the `tid` changes, you need to create a new dict and put it in `project_data`. `project_data` should be a dict as well, and the keys should be formed using `'row' + str(tid)` or something similar. When the tid does not change, update the dict as you already are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably simply changing the following things could work :

```
project_data = []
```

=>

```
project_data = {}
```

And

```
else:
    project_data.append(d)
```

to

```
else:
    d = {}
    project_data['row' + str(tid] = d
```

This should get you a structure closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: Great thanks, much closer! I changed .put to project_data[str(tid)] = d as I was getting a error with put. You've set me in the right track thank you!

Comment: yeah, sorry about the mixing up, I switching language several times a day these days.